# How to Override ETag Header in aiohttp's FileResponse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, aiohttp

I'm currently working with aiohttp in Python and using its FileResponse class to serve image files. I've an issue. I need to set my own custom ETag header, but it seems like FileResponse is automatically generating and using its own ETag header, which overrides my custom value.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def serve_image(request, image_path, etag, content_type):
    response = web.FileResponse(image_path)
    response.content_type = content_type
    response.headers["ETag"] = etag  # My custom ETag
    response.headers["My-ETag"] = etag
    # Other header settings...
    return response
```

When I check the response headers, I see that the ETag header is not what I set (etag variable) but appears to be automatically generated by FileResponse.

'My-ETag' is correct in response I use it for just double check.

I've tried setting the ETag header directly, as shown above, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to override or disable the automatic ETag generation in aiohttp's FileResponse? Or do I need to use a different approach to serve files with custom headers?

Comment: It does create its own etag, so that's probably overriding it as you expected:
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/23931465361cc366b97c1ef1b6419ea8dd2642a4/aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py#L138

There is probably no (designed) way to do this currently. Could be a good opportunity to make a contribution.